# Forecasting from Regression with auto.Arima() and defining xreg

Tags: r, time-series, arima

I am having an auction data set where the columns `End_of_week`, `Bid_Price`, `USD_INR`, `Crude_Oil_Price` and `Baltic_Dry_Index`, are present. I have to forecast the `Bid_Price` for the next 6 months. I have written the following code. There are two models created: one with data at level and second with log transformed data, but for both the models it displays:

> Regression with ARIMA(0,0,0) errors.

The data here provided is a part of the original data set.

**Data**

```
end_of_week L1_BID_PRICE    BDI_MA  Crude_Oil_Price USD_INR

27-01-2018  14.45   1184.4  66.14   63.59
03-02-2018  13.975  1153.2  65.45   64.13
10-02-2018  13.95   1101    59.2    64.375
17-02-2018  16.416  1101    61.68   64.215
24-02-2018  16.3    1140.4  63.55   64.71
03-03-2018  15.625  1194.8  61.25   65.22
10-03-2018  16.65   1202.2  62.04   65.125
17-03-2018  15.6    1166.6  62.34   64.99
24-03-2018  16.6    1122.8  65.88   64.99
31-03-2018  17.85   1100    64.94   65.115
```

**Code**

```
#ARIMA
# fit model1
covariates=c("BDI_MA","Crude_Oil_Price","USD_INR")
fit=auto.arima(train[,"L1_BID_PRICE"],xreg = train[,covariates])
fit
summary(fit)
fit$aic
fit$residuals

# forecast1
fcast <- forecast(fit, xreg = test[, covariates])
autoplot(fcast)

# fit model2
covariates=c("BDI_MA_log","Crude_Oil_Price_log","USD_INR_log")
fit=auto.arima(train[,"L1_BID_PRICE_log"],xreg = train[,covariates])
fit
summary(fit)
fit$aic
fit$residuals

# forecast2
fcast <- forecast(fit, xreg = test[, covariates])
autoplot(fcast)
accuracy(fcast)
```

Along with this I have a few queries in mind:

1. For declaring the Covariates, am I suppose to use the log transformed versions of `USD_INR`, `Crude_Oil_Price` and `Baltic_Dry_Index` or simply as they are?
2. Whether the response variable should be log transformed or not, while forecasting?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are testing additive (1st) and multiplicative (2nd) regression models. For multiplicative regression model response variable should be log-transformed and statistics are calculated based on log-transformed variables